# Small PSU with 110-240 Vac 50-60 Hz input and 12 V @ 1 A output

Tags: power-supply

I spent my day trying to find a functional schematic featuring those specifications:

- AC input voltage range of 100 to 240 V
- AC input frequency range of 50 to 60 Hz
- output is the easiest part, I can use either a LM317 or LM7812

I guess I can do something similar to (*after calculating values of course*)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMKAOY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My main question is about accepting the input voltage and frequency ranges mentioned above. How do I do that and build something quite small?

Any other concept can be accepted too, instead of my schematic if you feel this not optimized.

OK, so let's select a AC-to-DC converter module then. It should be the best solution for me - at those prices, I won't hesitate :)

Comment: There are ready made AC to DC modules that fit your requirements. You can even skip on  U1, Q1 and D3. They are available from the usual sources (Digikey, Mouser, Farnell, LCSC).

Comment: @francoisP, when you accept answer the system automatically marks the question solved. I've removed the "[solved]" from your question title as that is not how it's done on SE sites. Tips: 'V' for volt and 'Hz' for hertz. Capitalisation rules are the same for all SI units named after a person.

Comment: @Transistor, done, was cleaning up the question while you typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For universal input (generally 100 V to 240 V, 50 - 60 Hz) you will use a switched mode power supply. The switched mode regulation circuitry will maintain stable output voltage. Efficiency should be > 85%.

[image]

*Figure 1. SMPS block layout. Source: Wikipedia [Switched mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply).*

If you are interested in learning how they operate I suggest that you open some up (with power off, of course), try and find the switcher chip, get its part number and search for the datasheet. Very often you will find that the SMPS manufacturer has used the application note design with small modifications rather than risk designing from scratch. SMPS board layouts can be important as high frequencies are involved and if the manufacturer has a suggested layout this too will be adopted.

SMPS power supplies are not for beginners as any debugging would have to be done on live circuits with DC voltages of \$ \sqrt 2\$ times mains voltage. Remember the high voltage capacitors will take some time to discharge.

Adding a linear regulator is a poor design decision. It generates heat and reduces efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The key is a switch-mode power supply that can accept a wide range of input voltages.

'240 V' mains can be up to 260 Vrms, which is around 370 V peak. '110 V' mains can be lower than that, and you will want to be able to run while your input capacitors are sagging through the half cycle, so you'd like your first stage to work down to well below 100 VDC, a ratio of more than 4:1.

You will want isolation from mains to output, so must use a transformer.

A wide voltage range transformer is a perfect fit for a flyback. You 'charge up' the transformer core by connecting the primary to the rectified input. At 100 V, it takes a while to build up the current to your target level. At 370 V, it happens 4 times faster. Once you've reached the target current, you switch off and let the stored energy transfer to the secondary.

The actual secondary voltage defines what voltage the flyback will deliver its energy at. As a result of that single pulse of energy, the receiving capacitor will have increased in voltage a little.

That capacitor voltage is used to drive an isolating link, usually an opto-coupler, back to the primary side to time the next energy transfer pulse. Often, the capacitor is made large enough that the output ripple is low enough to use as it is. If you must have a linear regulator on the output, then you would control its input voltage to be just a little more than its dropout voltage, to minimise its inefficiency.

There are high voltages involved here, lots of opportunity for letting the smoke out and killing yourself or others. Better to buy a ready made design than to brew your own.

Answer (score 0):

Is a range switch acceptable for your design, of do you want to cover the entire input voltage range with no user action?

Assuming you do not want a range switch, and you don't want to get into switching power supply designs, then there is a simple linear solution; but - it is not very efficient.

If you start with a transformer rated for 240 input and a 30 Vac output, the output will reduce to 13.75 V with a 110 V input.  This is enough for the linear circuit you show, including the voltage losses in the rectifier diodes and the minimum input voltage of the 7812.

At 240 V in and 30 V out, the peak voltage across the filter capacitor will be approx. 40 V.  This is too high for a 7812, but within the normal range of an LM317.  At 1 A output current, wht 317 will dissipate approx. 28 watts.  That's a lot, and will require either a large heatsink, or a medium-sized heatsink with a small fan.

None of this is "quite small".  For that, nothing will beat buying a small switching power supply.  One option is to buy a 12 V "wall wart" for a few dollars on ebay, cut open the case and remove the pc board, and package it into your device.  NOTE: as with the linear supply you posted, the primary side has lethal voltages.